# How to get IDs of dynamically generated controls(buttons) in update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

**Webform2.aspx**

```
<div>
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
         <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
          </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnQuestions" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

            <asp:Button ID="btnQuestions" runat="server" Text="List of Questions" OnClick="btnQuestions_Click" />
        </div>
```

**Webform2.aspx.cs**

```
 protected void btnQuestions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.ID = i.ToString();
                btn.Text = "Goto Question No. - " + i.ToString();
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);
            }
        }
```

**View Page Source**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="WebForm2.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJMzc1Mjk4OTk4ZGSudUK/VecpFioiNgMDP9kj5zbQVtZPCn6WnVBaEsjwEw==" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=Qdmym63UMpMU1DJtVFnuUSbvrfXRh_dBOIoxTsIpZRgeov32_hKWuqEbYXBgt2nVBPk_BfLrvvSwnb3dE41Ss01NOvbPIs0qaLVWdw91Esk1&amp;t=635145356180000000" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=JwzAmVQVpITGxUtXHqHsNoS-RVwEUgrJeuMx8fcasEWLh6pC_B5U6DBCEmqJr6QsulrAlpuRr460-ujmC0zMiGfseMGkDsLZBsyJmuF2COzi1iL-SNRJHvkvxAhayUzHUP0eFCo09UvA7FrUPSsJv6AcuSY1gk8FbgpD08kqZYkPdKPGdgNK4k5EW51WZgFE0&amp;t=ca758f3" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
//]]>
</script>

<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=aeRoBGSEi2hF_mWyw0oQ_Sh_Za3-vBRjUPJkdBiNvwjHO4rVkXySp2rInQ9ypkBTiuT6Al0xTxoHspgmG8H-vO74_u918eJQOOIapzFgxexsRMuD9zP6fC_NYvi-aEnSmX2MzrA4s4USb0ZwsyhN2T96dYVrUVfcu6AKtIkdGD_fsUvAvd0xXk9X_quQDz980&amp;t=ca758f3" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAAK/BowZL5VcjJwbsBqeLE4F+Xa+cAn637jOZCAF7/zPZrl/RNRCLQxrlWwoFLpNj5PHdoMHRAzcBvdD/CSQHZuG" />
</div>
    <div>        
        <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ScriptManager1', 'form1', ['tUpdatePanel1','UpdatePanel1'], ['btnQuestions','btnQuestions'], [], 90, '');
//]]>
</script>

        <div id="UpdatePanel1">



</div>

        <input type="submit" name="btnQuestions" value="List of Questions" id="btnQuestions" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Question**
I want to call java-script function on Dynamically generated button controls. But, In view page source there is no such as following code under UpdatePanel1.

```
<input type="submit" name="1" value="Goto Question No. - 1" id="1" />
<input type="submit" name="2" value="Goto Question No. - 2" id="2" />
<input type="submit" name="3" value="Goto Question No. - 3" id="3" />
<input type="submit" name="4" value="Goto Question No. - 4" id="4" />
<input type="submit" name="5" value="Goto Question No. - 5" id="5" />
```

Also, I don't want to postback page(As other functionalities get affected ). like

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnQuestions" />
```

Comment: " But, In view page source there is no such as following code under UpdatePanel1." - did it generate after you click btnQuestions?

Comment: I am expecting such code under UpdatePanel1. Why because, I want call javascript function on Button ID.

Comment: But you wrote generation of additional buttons in btnQuestions_Click method. It wouldn't be there until you press btnQuestions. You can generate buttons on page load event and then use btnQuestions to make it visible or hide from user

Comment: Yes, on btnQuestions_Click update panel generate 5 buttons. I want ID of button clicked inside update panel. why not on page load, because I want to apply different color to button for attempted questions and not attempted questions (part not given in code).